# Spark - Update target data if primary keys match?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

Is it possible to overwrite a record in the target if specific conditions are met using spark without reading the target into a dataframe?  For example, I know we can do this if both sets of data are loaded into dataframes, but I would like to know if there is a way to perform this action without loading the target into a dataframe.  Basically, a way to specify overwrite/update conditions.

I am guessing no, but I figured I would ask before I dive into this project.  I know we have the write options of append and overwrite.  What I really want is, if a few specific columns already exist in the data target, then overwrite it and fill in the other columns with the new data.  For example:

File1:

```
id,name,date,score
1,John,"1-10-17",35
2,James,"1-11-17",43
```

File2:

```
id,name,date,score
3,Michael,"1-10-17",23
4,James,"1-11-17",56
5,James,"1-12-17",58
```

I would like the result to look like this:

```
id,name,date,score
1,John,"1-10-17",35
3,Michael,"1-10-17",23
4,James,"1-11-17",56
5,James,"1-12-17",58
```

Basically, Name and Date columns act like primary keys in this scenario.  I want updates to occur based on those two columns matching, otherwise make a new record.  As you can see id 4 overwrites id 2, but id 5 appends because the date column did not match.  Thanks ahead guys!

Comment: What do you mean by *without reading the target into a dataframe?* Remember that spark is lazy, so "reading" a file into a DataFrame does not actually do anything until you perform an action on it. In this case, the simplest thing is to do a join.

Comment: So, for example, when spark performs an overwrite.  Does it load the data that exists at the target into a dataframe?  If so, then my question is answered.  I was just hoping that the overwrite function would have been a lighter process than loading the entire target data set into a dataframe.

Comment: Spark is computational engine not a database. if you going to write in file based database, it does not support single record update. so for your case, you can use database such as cassandra which support update (if inserting same primary key) with high write throughput.